# Help to get partial differential from equation - robotics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, jacobian, robotics

I have system of two equations that describes position of robot end-effector ($X_C, Y_C, Z_C$), in accordance to prismatic joints position ($S_A, S_B$):

$S^2_A - \sqrt3(S_A + S_B)X_C = S^2_B + (S_A - S_B)Y_C$

$X^2_C + Y^2_C + Z^2_C = L^2 - S^2_A + S_A(\sqrt3X_C + Y_C)+M(S^2_A+S_BS_A + S^2_B)$

where M and L are constants.

In paper, author states that differentiating this system at 
given point ($X_C, Y_C, Z_C$) gives the "differential relationship" in form:

$a_{11}\Delta S_A + a_{12}\Delta S_B = b_{11}\Delta X_C + b_{12}\Delta Y_C + b_{13}\Delta Z_C$

$a_{21}\Delta S_A + a_{22}\Delta S_B = b_{21}\Delta X_C + b_{22}\Delta Y_C + b_{23}\Delta Z_C$

Later on, author uses those parameters ($a_{11}, a_{12}, b_{11}...$)
to construct matrices, and by multiplying those he obtains Jacobian
of the system.

Im aware of partial differentiation, but I have never done this for system of equations, neither I understand how to get those delta parameters.

Can anyone explain what are the proper steps to perform partial differentiation
on this system, and how to calculate delta parameters?

**EDIT**

Following advice given by N. Staub, I differentiated equations w.r.t time.

First equation:

$S^2_A - \sqrt3(S_A + S_B)X_C = S^2_B + (S_A - S_B)Y_C$
$=>$

$2S_A \frac{\partial S_A}{\partial t} -\sqrt3S_A \frac{\partial X_C}{\partial t} -\sqrt3X_C \frac{\partial S_A}{\partial t} -\sqrt3S_B \frac{\partial X_C}{\partial t} -\sqrt3X_C \frac{\partial S_B}{\partial t} = 2S_B\frac{\partial S_B}{\partial t} + S_A\frac{\partial Y_C}{\partial t} + Y_C\frac{\partial S_A}{\partial t} - S_B\frac{\partial Y_C}{\partial t} - Y_C\frac{\partial S_B}{\partial t}$

Second equation:

$X^2_C + Y^2_C + Z^2_C = L^2 - S^2_A + S_A(\sqrt3X_C + Y_C)+M(S^2_A+S_BS_A + S^2_B)$ $=>$

$2X_C \frac{\partial X_C}{\partial t} + 2Y_C \frac{\partial Y_C}{\partial t} + 2Z_C \frac{\partial Z_C}{\partial t} = -2S_A \frac{\partial S_A}{\partial t} + \sqrt3S_A \frac{\partial X_C}{\partial t} +\sqrt3X_C \frac{\partial S_A}{\partial t} + S_A \frac{\partial Y_C}{\partial t} + Y_C \frac{\partial S_A}{\partial t} + 2MS_A \frac{\partial S_A}{\partial t} + MS_B \frac{\partial S_A}{\partial t} + MS_A \frac{\partial S_B}{\partial t} + 2MS_B \frac{\partial S_B}{\partial t}$

then, I multiplied by $\partial t$, and grouped variables:

First equation:

$(2S_A -\sqrt3X_C - Y_C)\partial S_A +(-2S_B -\sqrt3X_C + Y_C)\partial S_B =  (\sqrt3S_A +\sqrt3S_B)\partial X_C + (S_A - S_B)\partial Y_C$

Second equation:

$(-2S_A+\sqrt3X_C+Y_C+2MS_A + MS_B)\partial S_A + (MS_A + 2MS_B)\partial S_B = (2X_C-\sqrt3S_A)\partial X_C + (2Y_C-S_A)\partial Y_C + (2Z_C)\partial Z_C$

therefore I assume that required parameters are:

$a_{11} = 2S_A -\sqrt3X_C - Y_C$

$a_{12} = -2S_B -\sqrt3X_C + Y_C$

$a_{21} = 2S_A + \sqrt3X_C + Y_C + 2MS_A + MS_B$

$a_{22} = MS_A + 2MS_B$

$b_{11} = \sqrt3S_A +\sqrt3S_B$

$b_{12} = S_A - S_B$

$b_{13} = 0$

$b_{21} = 2X_C - \sqrt3S_A$

$b_{22} = 2Y_C - S_A$

$b_{23} = 2Z_C$

Now. According to paper, jacobian of the system can be calculated as:

$J = A^{-1} B$,
where

$A=(a_{ij})$

$B=(b_{ij})$

so I im thinking right, it means:

$$
A =
    \begin{matrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$$
B =
    \begin{matrix}
    b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
    b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

and Jacobian is multiplication of reverse A matrix and B matrix.

Next, author states that Jacobian at given point, where

$X_C = 0$

$S_A=S_B=S$

$Y_C = l_t-\Delta\gamma$

is equal to:

$$
J =
    \begin{matrix}
    \frac{\sqrt3S}{2S-l_t+\Delta\gamma} & -\frac{\sqrt3S}{2S-l_t+\Delta\gamma}\\
    \frac{2(l_t-\Delta\gamma)-S}{6cS-2S+l_t-\Delta\gamma} & \frac{2(l_t-\Delta\gamma)-S}{6cS-2S+l_t-\Delta\gamma} \\
    \frac{2Z_C}{6cS-2S+l_t-\Delta\gamma} & \frac{2Z_C}{6cS-2S+l_t-\Delta\gamma} \\
    \end{matrix} ^T
$$

Everything seems fine. BUT! After multiplicating my A and B matrices I get some monster matrix, that I am unable to paste here, becouse it is so frickin large!
Substituting variables for values given by author does not give me proper jacobian (i tried substitution before multiplying matrices (on parameters), and after multiplication (on final matrix)).
So clearly Im still missing something. Either Ive done error in differentiation, or Ive done error in matrix multiplication (I used maple) or I dont understand how to subsititue those values. Can anyone point me in to right direction?

Comment: Have you tried implicit differentiation?

Comment: Yes, I've done implicit differentiation - I am able to differentiate single equation, but have no idea how to differentiatie both equations as system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/15712/help-to-get-robot-jacobian-from-system-of-implicit-equations

Link above directs to different thread, where problem has been solved.